# Google 2-step verification recovery

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth

I have the following scenario:

- a Google account with 2-step verification turned on
- verification is tied up to the iPhone app
- iPhone app got blown away accidentally
- however, the iPhone itself is perfectly ok and accessible
- the backup phone is inaccessible as its SIM-card has expired and the operator allocated this number to someone else
- the password for the Google account is of course known

How do I get access to my Google account? Is there any way to get Google to send a code to my phone number so I can sign in? The login interface only offering to sent the code to the backup number that I don't have access to. Maybe there is some "secret place" where I can ask to send it to my main phone number?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [Google Support site](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1099586&answer=1185133#lost). Beside suggesting to send codes to your secondary phone or using a trusted computer, it also explains another way for the worst case to get access by filling out a form:

> 1. Sign in to your account with your username and password.
> 2. On the verification code challenge page, click **Other ways to get a verification code?**
> 3. Click "I no longer have access to any of these."
> 4. You'll then need to fill out an account recovery form to verify ownership of the account. Take time to answer each question to the best of your ability. The form was designed to ensure that no one can gain access to your account except you. Since Google doesn't collect a lot of information about you when you sign up for an account, we will ask you questions like when you created your account, what Google services you use, and who you email frequently (if you use Gmail) to make certain you are authorized to access your account.

Good luck, and if you can gain access to your account, I **strongly** recommend you printing [**backup codes**](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1187538) and put them in a save place (or even mutliple places, you will get 10 codes)!